# Is there a way for me to have an event trigger on svn server

Tags: svn

On my SVN server, I want to execute a script after someone has committed something, and I am trying to figure out how to do this. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [post-commit hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html) that should help you with that.

Read [SVNBook | Implementing Repository Hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.hooks).